# Есть телеграм бот на aiogram. Есть django приложение с юзерами. Как подать сигнал в бот с джанги на рассылку сообщений?

Tags: python, django, асинхронность, broadcasting

Интересует вопрос реализации данной связки. Ткните носом в нужное направление

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from aiogram import Bot

API_TOKEN = 'BOT TOKEN HERE'

bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)

async_to_sync(bot.send_message(chat_id=123, text='Hello world!'))
```

Либо вместо iaogram использовать синхронный телеграм фреймворк, например - telepot. Таким образом вам не нужно будет импортировать и использовать async_to_sync.